# How should i create C-wrapper for c++ library which uses QtGui?

Tags: c++, c, qt, wrapper

I need to create C wrapper around qt-project, which will be used as a library. It uses simple functions of QPainter.

I created a class Qtx:

```
// -- Qtx.h --
#ifndef QTX_H
#define QTX_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>

class Qtx
{
    private:
    QPainter *painter;
    QPixmap *pix;

public:
    Qtx();
    QPixmap* getPixmap();
    void setPainterColor(int r, int g, int b);
    void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    void drawCircle(int x, int y, int radius);
    void drawEllipse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    void drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
};

#endif // QTX_H


// -- Qtx.cpp --
#include "qtx.h"

Qtx::Qtx()
{
    pix = new QPixmap(400,280);
    QPalette palette;
    pix->fill(palette.color(QPalette::Window));
    painter = new QPainter(pix);
}

QPixmap* Qtx :: getPixmap()
{
    return pix;
}

void Qtx::setPainterColor(int r, int g, int b)
{
    QPen *pen = new QPen(QColor(r, g, b));
    painter->setPen(*pen);
}

void Qtx :: drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    painter->drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}

void Qtx :: drawCircle(int x, int y, int radius)
{
    QPoint center(x, y);
    painter->drawEllipse(center, radius, radius);
}

void Qtx :: drawEllipse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    QRect rect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    painter->drawEllipse(rect);
}

void Qtx :: drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    QRect rect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    painter->drawRect(rect);
}
```

And created C-wrapper for this class:

```
/*qtx-c-wrapper.h*/
struct HQTx;

typedef struct HQTx HQTx;
HQTx * create();

void destroy(HQTx * h);

void setPainterColor(HQTx* v, int r, int g, int b);
void drawLine(HQTx* v, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
void drawCircle(HQTx* v, int x, int y, int radius);
void drawEllipse(HQTx* v, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
void drawRectangle(HQTx* v, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
```

But members of Qtx can only be used in MainWindow (as far as I know), for example:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "qtx.h"
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    Qtx* tx = new Qtx();
    QPixmap* p;
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);

    tx->setPainterColor(255,0,0);
    tx->drawCircle(100,100,90);

    p = tx->getPixmap();

    ui->setupUi(this);

    if(p != NULL)
    {
        label->setGeometry(0,0,400,280);
        label->setPixmap(*p);
        ui->centralWidget = label;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create C-wrapper for MainWindow? How should i do it?
I'm trying to create a library use it in C++ projects approximately as follows (just example):

```
#include "QtxLib.h"
int main()
    {
       QtxCreateWindow w = QtxCreateWindow (800, 600);

       QtxDrawLine (w, 320, 290, 320, 220);
       QtxCircle (w, 320, 190, 30);
       return 0;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite see what's your problem. The wrapper you've created for the Qtx class looks just like a wrapper for `QMainWindow` would look like - except that for custom-painted widgets you **do not** wish a `QMainWindow`, but a simple `QWidget` or `QLabel`. If you wrote the code above yourself, you already know the answer. If not, please say what is your *exact* problem.

Comment: @KubaOber I didn't think that I can use QLabel without QMainWindow. Now I just put code from MainWindow to Qtx members. It works. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, I don't know if you really need a `QMainWindow` at all. If you don't need its specific functionality (dock areas, central widget, status/menu bars, etc.), you shouldn't be using it at all. A plain `QWidget` is good enough. If all you have is some text to show, you can show a plain `QLabel`. The `QMainWindow` is a really poor name for a class - it's no more "main" than anything else.